# How to provide pre-compiled cython modules for 32 and 64 bits neatly?

Tags: python, cython

I have a python script using a cython module I wrote. I want to publish it, and in order to save users the trouble of compiling the cython stuff (especially complex on Windows), I want to provide pre-compiled extensions.

However, I will need one version for 32 bits and another for 64. I thought about including the two files as mymodule32.pyd and mymodule64.pyd, and then, mymodule.py doing the following:

```
if bits == 32:
    from mymodule32 import *
elif bits == 64:
    from mymodule64 import *
```

But this feels a litle clumsy. What if the user decides to compile the module himself producing mymodule.pyd?

Comment: Can't you just provide two separate downloads, each containing a file `mymodule.pyd`?

Comment: Could you provide them both and just tell users to rename the appropriate one `mymodule.pyd` (or do it in the installer, if there is one)?

Comment: I can. martineau's suggestion appears simple and good enough. Thank you!

Comment: The Linux way -- get one installed in `..../lib32/` and the other in `..../lib64/`. The Mac way -- universal binary (dunno if universal DSO is possible). The windows way -- installer hacks (?). The hackish way -- try loading one, then another :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My impression is that this is part of how you package your module and publishing it on pypi, not about how you import it.

The import is supposed not to care about your architecture, is the module installation and package that needs to know about this.